# Finding files and matching patterns with printed filename in bash

Tags: bash, grep, find, pattern-matching

I have the following code that lists matches far a pattern `ptrn`, with the filename being printed before the listing (which uses the context option `-C NUM`)

```
find "$fdir" "${isufx[*]}" -type f -exec bash -c  \
  "grep --color -l '$ptrn' '{}'; grep --color -ni ${ictx[*]} '$ptrn' '{}'" \;
```

I agree it's a monster.  I decided to remove the `bash -c` call,
resulting in

```
  OFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  for f in $(find "$fdir" ${isufx[*]} -type f); do
    grep -l "$ptrn" "$f" && grep -ni ${ictx[*]} "$ptrn" "$f"
  done
  IFS=$OFS
```

Any suggestions on the above?  I would like to print the filename before the listing, enclosed between `==>` and `<==`, with an empty line above and below the filename.

After suggestions about avoiding looping over `find`'s output, I have:

```
  find "$fdir" ${isufx[*]} -type f |
    while read f; do
      grep -l "$ptrn" "$f" && grep -ni ${ictx[*]} "$ptrn" "$f"
    done
```

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: That will fork one instance of bash and two of grep (both grepping the same file) for every single file found by `find`.  That's kind of horrifying.  Replace it with an `awk` or `perl` script that does the pattern matching, the colourisation, and the context lines. Hint: for the context, the script will have to remember NUM lines before the current line, just in case it matches and then print those lines, the current line and the next NUM lines).   Using `find ... -exec ... +` instead of `\;`, that will fork one process total (not 3 per file), which will make only one pass through all files.

Comment: For extra fun, have the script parse `$GREP_COLORS` (plural), or the older/simpler/deprecated `$GREP_COLOR` (singular),  environment variables if they exist, otherwise default to the same colours as `grep`.   See `man grep` and search for the section titled "ENVIRONMENT" for details.

Comment: Don't use a for loop with find like that.  See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're not going to like this answer, but here's *a* correct way of doing this (not **the** correct way, but one of many).   It's here as an example for those who want to know that it's not terribly difficult to write your own custom tools when the standard tools, like grep, don't do quite what you want them to do - this is how unix is meant to be used.  (and also because I wanted to find out how difficult it would be to parse and use grep's GREP_COLORS variable...trivially easy, as it turned out)

It's a script that only needs to be forked once by `find ... -exec` and does everything in one pass through each file, rather then multiple passes.   It handles **any** valid filename, even those containing newlines and other white space.

Save the `perl` script below as, e.g., `context-grep.pl` and make it executable with `chmod +x context.pl`.  Then run it like so:

```
find "$fdir" "${isufx[*]}" -type f -exec ./context-grep.pl {} +
```

It will use the following environment variables:

- `$ptrn` for the pattern to search for
- `$NUM` for the number of context lines to print (optional, default is 3)
- `$GREP_COLOR` or `$GREP_COLORS` to use the same colour code as `grep` (optional, defaults to green).

These can, as usual, be specified on the command line, e.g.

```
NUM=5 ptrn='foo.*bar' find "$fdir" "${isufx[*]}" -type f -exec ./context-grep.pl {} +
```

Proper option handling for the script could be done with one of perl's many option processing modules (like [Getopt::Std](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Std) or [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long)) but this script is already getting too long for this site.   The whole thing could have been written in perl without needing `find` with the [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find) module.  All three of these modules are core perl library modules and are included with perl.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

# This script should use TERM::TERMCAP to get the actual
# colour codes for the current $TERM from the terminfo
# database, but I'll just hard-code it to use ANSI colour
# codes because almost everything is ansi-compatible these days.
# That's good enough for grep, so it's good enough for this.

###
### variable setup and related stuff
###

my $sgr0 = "\033[m\017";
my $colour = "\033[01;32m"; # default to green

# If either of grep's colour env vars are defined, use
# them instead. (the newer $GREP_COLORS is checked last,
# so has precedence over $GREP_COLOR)
if ($ENV{'GREP_COLOR'}) {
  $colour = "\033[$ENV{'GREP_COLOR'}m";
};

if ($ENV{'GREP_COLORS'}) {
  # e.g. ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36
  # This script really only cares about the ms value
  # It wouldn't be hard to make it use `mc` as well to print the
  # context lines in a different colour than the match line.
  my @GC = split /:/, $ENV{'GREP_COLORS'};
  foreach (@GC) {
    if (m/^ms/) {
      my (undef,$c) = split /=/;
      $colour = "\033[${c}m";
      last;
    }
  };
};

my $search=$ENV{'ptrn'};
my @context;

my $NUM=3; # default to 3 lines of context
$NUM = $ENV{'NUM'} if (defined($ENV{'NUM'}));

my $last = -1;

my $first_match=1;

###
### main loop, process the input file(s)
###

while(<>) {
  chomp;

  if ($. <= $last) {
    # current line is an AFTER context line, print it
    printf "%s%s%s\n", $colour, $_, $sgr0;

  } elsif (m/$search/) {
    # We've found a match! handle it.

    # print filename like head & tail does if this is the
    # first match we've found in the current file.
    if ($first_match) {
      printf "\n==> %s <==\n\n", $ARGV;
      $first_match=0;
    };

    # print the remembered BEFORE context lines
    foreach my $l (@context) {
      printf "%s%s%s\n", $colour, $l, $sgr0;
    };

    # print current line
    printf "%s%s%s\n", $colour, $_, $sgr0;

    # clear the context array 
    @context=();

    # set $last so we can print the AFTER context lines
    $last = $. + $NUM;

  } else {
    # remember the last $NUM lines of context
    push @context, $_;                     # add current C line
    shift @context if ($#context >= $NUM); # remove first C line
  };

  # reset $last, $first_match, and the input record counter
  # ($. - equivalent to awk's NR) on every EOF
  if (eof) {
    close(ARGV);
    $last = -1;
    $first_match=1;
  };
};
```

BUGS: there's absolutely no error handling. Or option processing. or help/usage message. or POD documentation.  These are left as an exercise for the reader.

Sample output (the matched line and 2 lines of context around pattern "chomp" from the script itself):

```
$ NUM=2 ptrn=chomp find . -type f -name '*.pl' -exec ./context-grep.pl {} +

==> ./context-grep.pl <==


while(<>) {
  chomp;

  if ($. <= $last) {
```

I have `export GREP_COLOR='0;33'` in my `~/.bashrc` so the matched line and context lines are printed in yellow. The filename is printed in the terminal's default text colour (white on a black background).

Answer (score 0):

I put another solution that uses `grep` without `find`.

```
echo ""
grep -rl ${isufx[@]} "$ptrn" $fdir |
  while read f; do
    echo -e $(tput setaf 46)"==> $f <==\n"$(tput sgr0)
    grep -ni ${ictx[@]} "$ptrn" "$f"
    echo ""
  done
```